# AlarmManager doesn't start currently opening activity

Tags: android, android-alarms

My `AlarmActivity` is `singleInstance`.
I register to AlarmManager with this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Problem: when alarm goes off while `AlarmActivity` is currently opening, it can't be started.

I'm looking for a clean simple solution to call a method in `AlarmActivity` when alarm goes off (can be onStart() onResume()...).

I don't want to use Service or BroadcastReceiver. Is this possible?

Comment: consider using job scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you add alarm code in onResume().

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    cancelAlarm();

    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() + 60*1000; //1 minute After
    String timestamp = tsLong.toString();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(timestamp));

    setAlarm(timestamp);
}

public void cancelAlarm() {
    PendingIntent pIntent = createPendingIntent();
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pIntent);
    pIntent.cancel();

}

public PendingIntent createPendingIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class);

    return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

}

public void setAlarm(Calendar calendar, PendingIntent pIntent) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
    }
}
```

Then, AlarmActivity will create every minute.